# "Error converting data type varchar to float" message in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I was given a script which will copy the contents of a table (from the sandbox) into another table (staging), but I keep getting "Error converting data type varchar to float" message.

Here's the code:

```
INSERT INTO First_DB.Orig_Table
(CustomerNo, AccountGroupID, ComCode)

SELECT A.CustomerNo, A.AccountGroupID, A.ComCode
FROM Test_DB.DBO.viewCMMasterData A
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT B.CustomerNo
                 FROM First_DB.Orig_Table B
                 WHERE B.CustomerNo = A.CustomerNo)
```

***Test_DB.DBO.viewCMMasterData*** is under the Views folder and is tied with a table named ***dbo.cmMasterData*** which is also residing in the ***Test_DB*** database.

As for the data types,

**First_DB.Orig_Table**

```
CustomerNo (PK, varchar(10), not null)
AccountGroupID (int, null)
ComCode (varchar(4), null)
```

**Test_DB.DBO.viewCMMasterData**

```
CustomerNo (nvarchar(255), null)
AccountGroupID (smallint, not null)
ComCode (varchar(4), not null)
```

I tried using ***CAST()*** but to no avail.

Please let me know if I still need to provide additional details.

Comment: Try running both queries in your select separately. Do they run correctly?

Comment: The first one works fine, but in the second SELECT statement, I substituted A.CustomerNo with an actual value and it also worked (but with empty result).

Answer (score 0):

You both table's CustomerNo's datatype is differ and I think in viewCMMasterData table have float value which is not convert into varchar format, Even you cast it gives the same error.

Find out the value which is non-text value i.e. numeric value. The reason cast or convert only apply when your data is appropriately.

please use cast as , also give width. The issue also because of width. The data may be truncated.

```
INSERT INTO First_DB.Orig_Table
(CustomerNo, AccountGroupID, ComCode)

SELECT cast ( A.CustomerNo as varchar(10) ) , A.AccountGroupID, A.ComCode
FROM Test_DB.DBO.viewCMMasterData A
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT B.CustomerNo
                 FROM First_DB.Orig_Table B
                 WHERE B.CustomerNo = A.CustomerNo)
```

I test as local and it work for me.

```
declare @t table (customerno nvarchar(255), AccountGroupID smallint, ComCode varchar(4))
declare @t1 table (customerno varchar(10), AccountGroupID int, ComCode varchar(4))

insert into @t values ('abc',1,'a'),('120.33',2,'a'),('xna',1,'a')
insert into @t1 values ('abc',1,'a')

select * from @t
select * from @t1

insert into @t1 
select * from @t a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT B.CustomerNo
                 FROM @t1 B
                 WHERE B.CustomerNo = A.CustomerNo)

select * from @t
select * from @t1

insert into @t values ('123456.6',1,'a')--,('12345678910.35466',1,'a') --if remove this comment, then gives below error.

insert into @t1 
select * from @t a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT B.CustomerNo
                 FROM @t1 B
                 WHERE B.CustomerNo = A.CustomerNo)
-- the above statement give me error as, other wise everything transfer
"String or binary data would be truncated."

select * from @t
select * from @t1
```

Comment: Why could there be conversion to float given that one column is `varchar` and the other is `nvarchar`?

Comment: Because you have any float value in Customer No column of viewCMMasterData table.  Nvarchar is given , may be bacause it accept unicode value which is not done in varchar.

Comment: So you're saying the value '123.55' stored in a `varchar` column gets treated as `float`?

Comment: Just to add, I imported the data from an excel file to the Test_DB and the CustomerNo column was numeric. What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you very sure the column type is `varchar` in the **table**? Read this to see if the cases mentioned in the Troubleshooting section might have occurred in your case: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321686

Comment: Good to same datatype used, also good to make customer no, not to pk. But use another column like customerid auto-increment true.

Comment: @shree.pat18, yes. I looked at the structure again and yes, they are both varchar.

Comment: @Ajay2707: I tried using CAST() as you have suggested in your code and it gave me something like this for the customerNo: 5.03744e+008

Comment: Ohhh I got it, the numveric value is exceeding in excel and while importing, it store as this and also the length (select len(5.03744e+008)) is exceding from varhcar(10). So when you insert in gives error. I just copy and paste in excel , it gives me 503744000 of above value. To rectify, You first double click of all column of csv, so gives the actual numeric value. then import it.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, I got the script to work with some minor adjustments. Instead of using *A.CustomerNo*, I just used the actual value for comparing. Here's my code:

```
INSERT INTO CCBP_PhaseII.customer.CM_MRWrkFieldsForMtnc
(CustomerNo, AccountGroupID, ComCode)
SELECT CAST(A.CustomerNo as INT), A.AccountGroupID, A.ComCode
FROM TEST_C1MDM_DB.DBO.viewCMMasterData A
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT B.CustomerNo
                 FROM CCBP_PhaseII.customer.CM_MRWrkFieldsForMtnc B
                 WHERE B.CustomerNo = '503744242')
```

I know this is not an efficient way of solving this problem, especially if you're transferring multiple records from 1 table to another. I hope you can give me more advice to improve this solution. Thanks to everyone who have responded!